# Excel VBA macro fails when loaded from server, works when run from local disk?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro in VBA. In short it runs on Auto_Open, displays a dialog box for user to enter some data, and when mandatory fields are filled, it populates a sheet in excel and saves as PDF or prints. Everything works perfectly, if the .xlsm file is opened from local disk (including opening from website, saving and then opening). However, if the .xlsm file is opened directly from a web server (intranet), everything works until the user tries to save as PDF or print. The error message is:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application defined or object-defined error

and the offending line of code is:

```
Sheets("hakemus_laaja_FI (2)").Name = "hakemus"
```

(at the time of the error a sheet named "hakemus_laaja_FI (2)" exists on the workbook, whereas there is no sheet named "hakemus")

Furthermore, if the user doesn't have Office 365 but an older version of Excel, then even opening the .xlsm file directly from website works perfectly.

Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Comment: Is it being opened in protected view?

Comment: Please [edit] your original question and show the complete code of the procedure that runs when the file is opened, or at least a [mcve].

Comment: It opens in protected view, after which the user clicks "enable editing". Then the user is asked whether to make it a trusted document and finally the user is asked to enable macros. All this is required to start the macro in the first place.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example. To do this, I moved the original .xlsm file to another site, and noticed that when loaded from there, the problem disappears. So far the problem is only reproducible when the .xlsm file is opened directly from the company intranet.